# How to set cron job correct path to run a node.js script?

Tags: cron, scheduling, node.js

I'm trying to automate a Node.js file to run on schedule.
But I can't get it to work.

I'm using **root** user.

This is the path to get to the file location from login:
`nodejs_projects/amazon_search_v2`

Here is pwd output from the login location:

```
root@project:~# pwd
/root
```

And this is the script i'm adding in **crontab** :

```
0 4,12,20 * * * node nodejs_projects/amazon_search_v2/searchItemsApi.js  >/dev/null 2>&1
```

What am i'm missing here?

Comment: Do you get any errors from cron when it tries to execute your job? Errors are usually emailed to the owner of the job.  What are the other symptoms of the job not working?

Comment: It's just that nothing is happening, no errors that I see. I'm not sure there is an email configured, it's a new digital ocean droplet machine.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

`* 0,8,16 * * * cd ~/nodejs_projects/amazon_search_v2/ && /usr/bin/node searchItemsApi.js >/dev/null 2>&1`

As described here:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849402/how-can-you-execute-a-node-js-script-via-a-cron-job/5849463)

In Curtis Xiao answer.
Using `which node` to find the node executable path and `cd` to get into the file folder and prevent relative path issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the full path. I would try to execute it this way

```
/root/nodejs_projects/amazon_search_v2/searchItemsApi.js
```

You have to specify the full path to `node` as well.

Comment: There is another path involved in executing the job, and that's the path of the `node` executable. Also, we don't know what crontab the user added the job to (root's personal crontab or the system crontab, which uses a different format).

Comment: I use root user login and  then  ```crontab -e``` to edit to cron file. so I guess it's root's personal crontab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, simply specify the path to node and the path to the script to be executed like so:

```
* 0,8,16 * * * /bin/node /path/to/script/to/execute.js
```

That's all.

Comment: Obuntu..? Ubuntu for eReaders?